# SQL Query on nested selection with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

In this, I want to select the average of values in value column based on a nested condition:

1. Firstly, I should Group By "Cluster". If there is even a single or more 'N',I take the average of that, and mark it as OUTPUT COLUMN For that cluster.
   Extra Condition:
2. If there are all Y's (HCF Y/N Column) in that Cluster(example BC2), group by column "PL" and
   then take average of those values.
3. If there are all Y's in PL(example PL2), group by "Plant" and take average of those values.
4. If there are all Y's in Plant, you mark default value of N/A.

All the above selection has to implied on that cluster for that BG+Mat+Plant combination.
How do I form a SQL Query for this?

[image: This is the Sample for it]

Comment: Please don't link to images of data, add the information as editable text to your question 1) It is much harder to understand your question when the information and data are in different places 2) if someone wants to try out a possible solution they need to be able to copy your data, rather than having to manually type it

Comment: 1) Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO script. 2) Sample data must include the groups for each condition in your conditions list. 3) Provide desired output for this sample data. 4) Specify precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are rather hard to follow because your image only includes one or two of them.  But you seem to want conditional window averages:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(hcv = 'N') over (partition by cluster) > 0
             then avg(value) over (partition by cluster)
             when sum(hcv = 'N') over (partition by pl) > 0
             then avg(value) over (partition by pl)
             when sum(hcv = 'N') over (partition by plant) > 0
             then avg(value) over (partition by plant)
        end) as output
from t;
```

Note that the default value is `NULL`, not `'N/A'`.  `AVG()` returns a number and that should not be mixes with strings.